# Using array as react hook useState

Tags: reactjs

I am using array as value of useState

also I need to change only one element and set it as state

```
const Main = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

    function TestFunction({state, setState}): JSX.Element {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              border: '1px solid black', height: '100px', width: '100%', display: ' block',
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              const qwer = state;
              qwer[2] -= 1;
              setState(qwer);
    
              console.log('clicked', state);
            }}
          >{test}
          </div>
        );
      }
    
    return (
        <TestFunction state={test} setState={setTest} />
    );
}
```

console says that the value "test" has been changed,

But it never rerenders it.

Am I using wrong? If so, I want to ask some solution please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making a copy of an array with the `=` operator. Infact you are mutating the state there. Use `...` spread operator:

```
onClick={() => {
              const qwer = [...state];
              qwer[2] -= 1;
              setState(qwer);
    
              console.log('clicked', state);
            }}
```

Comment: **Note to OP:** logging `state` right _after_ calling `setState` will log the _old_ state, not the updated state. Component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. Use the `useEffect` hook to log the updated state: `useEffect(() => { console.log(state) }, [state]);`

Answer (score 1):

React works on the principle of [immutability](https://flaviocopes.com/react-immutability/); whenever an element changes in your state, you shouldn't *mutate* the underlying value, but instead construct a brand new object with your changes. This is the only way for React to realize the state has changed as under the hood it does `oldState===newState`which will always pass, even if you change an index of an array (since they both refer to the same place in memory).

To apply this here, you would do:

```
const Main = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

    function TestFunction({state, setState}): JSX.Element {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              border: '1px solid black', height: '100px', width: '100%', display: ' block',
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              // ---------- New Changes ---------- \\
              // [...state] clones the array here
              const qwer = [...state];
              
              qwer[2] -= 1;
              setState(qwer);
              // Note: This will print the old value, you will need to
              // wait for the next re-render to get the new state, or 
              // just log qwer 
              console.log('clicked', qwer);
            }}
          >{test}
          </div>
        );
      }
    
    return (
        <TestFunction state={test} setState={setTest} />
    );
}
```